# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate') React Native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho essa função signOut que eu chamo através de um botão, porém quando eu aperto no sair, onde ele chama um `onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')` ele retorna o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como posso corrigir isso?

Versões: 
**react:** "16.8.3",
**react-native:** "0.59.3",
**react-native-gesture-handler:** "^1.1.0",
**react-navigation:** "^3.6.0"

Comment: Não entendi a resposta marcada como certa. Em qual local ou em que momento faço isso, Sidebar é o componente customizado ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que deve estar acontecendo é o seguinte, quando você utiliza o React Navigation, o "navigation" é passado como props para as páginas que você colocar na rota. Porém, dentro desta página, os componentes não tem acesso ao navigation.  Então se eu tiver nesta página um botão e usar o "navigation.navigate" ele vai funcionar, mas, se esta página tiver um componente, e dentro dele você tentar fazer o mesmo, não vai funcionar.

Para resolver isso, basta criar uma props e passar o navigation para ele. Seria algo assim

```
<Sidebar navigation= {this.props.navigation} />
```

Desta forma, o seu botão deve funcionar.

Comment: Entendi! Valeu mesmo, funcionou aqui!!